# Java: NoSuchMethodException even though the method exists

Tags: java, reflection

So I have a class with 2 public methods defined. When I call getDeclaredMethods, then loop over the results, printing the names, both correctly show up. So not only does the method exist, but the reflection call finds it.

But when I try calling the method, like in the code below, I get a NoSuchMethodException. So why can't it find it when invoking?

```
public class Foo
{
  public byte[] read_status(Object arg)
  {
    byte[] test = new byte[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      test[i] = (byte)i;
    }
    return test;
  }

  public int test(String s) throws Exception
  {
    Object r = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("read_status").invoke(this, (Object)s);
    byte[] bytes = (bytes[])r;
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(""+bytes[i]);
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: `get(Declared)Method()` expects the *signature* of the method as its identification, and the signature consists of the name (`read_status`) and the parameter list of that method (`Object.class`). Your code (`….getDeclaredMethod( "read_status" ).…`) just looks for a method `Foo.read_status()` – taking *no* arguments. To add to the confusion: the return value (or its type) is not part of the signature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put the parameters' types of the method, your code should look like this:

```
public int test(String s) throws Exception {
    Object r = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("read_status", Object.class).invoke(this, (Object)s);
    byte[] bytes = (byte[])r;
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(""+bytes[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize I needed that 2nd param in getDeclaredMethod.